# Plone 4.3 and transmogrifier installation

Tags: migration, plone, transmogrifier

I am trying to migrate content from old 3.x Plone installation to new Plone 4.3 instance. Both are running on windows platforms.

In new 4.3 installation I am trying to install quintagroup.transmogrifier and instance does not start.
bin\instance.exe fg gives following:

clip
Presumably normal entries removed...
clip

```
  File "c:\plone43\eggs\zope.configuration-3.7.4-py2.7.egg\zope\configuration\config.py", line 179, in resolve
    mod = __import__(mname, *_import_chickens)
  File "c:\plone43\eggs\quintagroup.transmogrifier-0.4-py2.7.egg\quintagroup\transmogrifier\writer.py", line 13, in <module>
    import quintagroup.transmogrifier.patches
  File "c:\plone43\eggs\quintagroup.transmogrifier-0.4-py2.7.egg\quintagroup\transmogrifier\patches.py", line 89, in <module>
    from tarfile import nts, GNUTYPE_SPARSE, normpath
zope.configuration.xmlconfig.ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "c:\Plone43\parts\instance\etc\site.zcml", line 15.2-15.55
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "c:\Plone43\parts\instance\etc\package-includes\002-quintagroup.transmogrifier-configure.zcml", line 1.0-1.70
    ZopeXMLConfigurationError: File "c:\plone43\eggs\quintagroup.transmogrifier-0.4-py2.7.egg\quintagroup\transmogrifier\configure.zcml", line 67.4-70.10
    ImportError: cannot import name normpath
```

Is this something that transmogrifier is not allowd to load python module (v.2.7) in Plone or cannot find it from windows?

How could I fix the issue or approach it further?

I tried, just to copy data.fs to new site, but it seems to import a lot of "crap" from old version as well and some of the functionality dows not work properly.

I am not thet familiar with Plone/Zope/Python, but so far I have managed to get the job done.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in `quintagroup.transmogrifier` that [has been fixed](https://github.com/collective/quintagroup.transmogrifier/commit/f3d5a50563a6d648d648ea324e35ba1766492204) but not yet released.

For now, you can use the version on Github. If you are using [mr.developer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer), the easiest way  is to amend your `buildout.cfg` as follows:

```
[sources]
quintagroup.transmogrifier = git git://github.com/collective/quintagroup.transmogrifier.git
```